# What the purpose of "the following steps are performed in place of step 29"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading [EcmaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation), at the section 9.2.12, the step 29 is:

> NOTE: Annex B.3.3 adds additional steps at this point

Then I go to reading the annex B.3.3, I find this:

> [following steps are performed in place of step 29](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics)

At the end, there is:

> If an ECMAScript implementation has a mechanism for reporting diagnostic warning messages, a warning should be produced for each function whose function code contains a FunctionDeclaration for which steps 1.a.ii.1-3 will be performed

To be honest,I don't know it's meaning or I don't know what's the purpose of it.

So, can you help me to sum up what the step 29 do?

Thanks.

Comment: It defines how function declarations inside blocks should be evaluated. That's explained at the beginning of the section: *"Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript specification did not define the occurrence of a FunctionDeclaration as an element of a Block statement’s StatementList. However, support for that form of FunctionDeclaration was an allowable extension and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations permitted them. [...] ECMAScript 2015 interoperability for the second and third use cases requires the following extensions to the clause 9 and clause 14 semantics."*

Comment: The part you cited just means that the environment should issue a warning if a function declaration exists to which these steps apply.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks.I try to write some code to trigger the warning, but it does't work.Can you give me a example which can trigger the warning?